# How to make "=> Booting Puma" log as JSON format in Rails 7? (How to override method print_boot_information in Rails?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I want to format following log into JSON:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.4.2 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
```

Afaik, this line is produced by this code https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7c70791470fc517deb7c640bead9f1b47efb5539/railties/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb#L278-L284

Commit ID [7c70791 is related to Rails 7.0.4.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v7.0.4.2) which the latest version that I used in my app.

The reason why I want format it into JSON is I want all produced log is in JSON, so there is no more unstructured log in my application.

### My question

How to override the `print_boot_information` method to make it show as JSON?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried to create file lib/custom_server_command.rb with this code:

```rb
require "rails/commands"

module Rails
  module Command
      class ServerCommand < Base
        def print_boot_information
          logs = [
            "Booting #{ActiveSupport::Inflector.demodulize(server)}",
            "Rails #{Rails.version} application starting in #{Rails.env} #{url}",
            "Run `#{executable} --help` for more startup options"
          ]

          logs.each do |log|
            json_log = {
              msg: log,
            }.to_json

            puts(json_log)
          end
        end
      end
  end
end
```

and change the `bin/rails` file into this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path("../config/application", __dir__)
require_relative "../config/boot"
require "rails/commands"
require_relative "../lib/custom_server_command"
```

(Adding `require_relative "../lib/custom_server_command"` in the last line).

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will have to change the code a bit, and then add it to the bottom of `config/boot.rb`:

```rb
require "rails/command" # Allow for base class autoload
require "rails/commands/server/server_command" # Load the ServerCommand class

Rails::Command::ServerCommand.class_eval do
  def print_boot_information(server, url)
    logs = [
      "Booting #{ActiveSupport::Inflector.demodulize(server)}",
      "Rails #{Rails.version} application starting in #{Rails.env} #{url}",
      "Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options"
    ]

    logs.each do |log|
      json_log = {
        msg: log,
      }.to_json

      puts(json_log)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Glad to hear it solved your problem!